# SQL query for backfilling register read values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with ID,timestamp,register reads for a day, the register reads are like running totals starts at 12.00 at midnight and ends at 11.00 at night. 
Problem is there are some random timeintervals in which the cumulative reads may not be present, I need to back fill those,
[image]

The below picture gives a snapshot of the problem, The KWH_RDNG is the difference between two cumulative intervals divided by 1000, but the 4th column 5.851 is actually accumulation of 3 missing hours along with the 4th hour value. its fine if i simply divide 5.851/4 and distribute it. 
The challenge is they can happen at random intervals and it can be different for different meters (1st column). I am using SQL Server 2016.
Please help.!!

Comment: Sample input/output?

Comment: Are you saying you want to update the table and replace the 0's and NULLs with some other values?

Comment: @RavitejaVutukuri The table screenshot above is a sample input. I just need a select query using that table which can backfill those zeros and replace them with the immediate value 5.851 / (number of zeros) .. (like a case statement or something).

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, I want a select query which can replace the 0's or NULLs with average of the 5.851 value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem -- sort of.  You need to identify groups of `NULL` values with the subsequent value.  One method is to use a cumulative sum of the non-`NULL` value *on or after* each value.  This defines the groups.

Then, you need the count and the reading.  So, this should do the calculation:

```
select t.*,
       (max_kwh_rding / cnt) as new_kwh_rding
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by meter_serial, grp) as cnt,
             max(kwh_rding) over (partition by meter_serial, grp) as max_kwh_rding
      from (select t.*,
                   count(kwh_rding) over (partition by meter_serial order by read_utc desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (max_kwh_rding / cnt) as new_kwh_rding
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by meter_serial, grp) as cnt,
                   max(kwh_rding) over (partition by meter_serial, grp) as max_kwh_rding
            from (select t.*,
                         count(kwh_rding) over (partition by meter_serial order by read_utc desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      where cnt > 1
     )
update toupdate
    set kwh_rding = max_kwh_rding;
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this out and let you know. :)